# How to use variables in Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a silly ask. I am using roles and variables in my playbook but getting an error while executing. Here is the heriarchy of my plays

my-main.yml

```
---
 - include: validation-and-download-tasks.yml
```

validation-and-download-tasks.yml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
     - role: valanddownload
       tags:
         - valanddownload
```

valanddownload main.yml

```
---
 - name: Validating the input variables
   #hosts: localhost
   #gather_facts: false

   vars:
     _allowed_envs:
       - dev
       - preprod
       - prod

 - name: Ensuring that directory exists to download the artifacts
   file:
     path: "{{ release_location }}/{{my_release_version}}"
     state: directory
```

Something wrong with my indentation? Error below

```
ERROR: vars is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler
```

Comment: In `valanddownload main.yml`, you have defined `vars` in a task. It should be at the play level.

Comment: @franklinsijo Hi Frank, do you mean yo say it should be defined in validation-and-download-tasks.yml? Could you please elaborate, it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

as written, you should define the vars on the play level, here's an example as you asked:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
     - role: valanddownload
       tags:
         - valanddownload
  vars:
    _allowed_envs:
      - dev
      - preprod
      - prod
```

You can't attach the vars part to the task level. This should work for you.

Tip: I would use a vars file. Define all your variables there. It is much more comfortable and editable to control all your vars in one file.